# Is there a way to prevent a Macbook Air from sleeping when external monitor is plugged in but power is not?

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, power, display

I have a 13-inch Mid 2012 Macbook Air running 10.9.3. I usually run with the lid closed plugging into 2 Apple cinema displays. Everything works great, except when I accidentally bump the power cable, at which point it goes to sleep.

Is there any way to prevent this? Clearly it isn't a power issue, because with the lid open and no power cable it drives all 3 monitors just fine.

Comment: I think it's possible, if you're comfortable with terminal stuff. Back in a moment with that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The power adapter is required for closed display mode on any Apple portable machine, without it you can't use closed display mode.

Reference:  http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3131

There is however a third party solution, called Caffine.  Which when enabled, forces the mac to stay on until the battery dies, it won't ever sleep.

http://lightheadsw.com/caffeine/

Comment: Thanks, the issue is that now I have to remember to enable/disable Caffeine when I want to switch between these behaviors. It would be nice if there was something conditional on the power adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping to figure out how to do this with the [pmset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pmset) utility ([man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pmset.1.html)). I feel like it's possible, but I couldn't see anything obvious (to me) looking through the options.

Anyway, here's another app that will do what you want: https://code.google.com/p/macosx-nosleep-extension/

Comment: Bummer, I've looked into the no sleep extension, and again the issue is I have to remember to enable/disabled it. For now I just moved my laptop into a spot where it's a lot harder to accidentally bump the power cable.

Comment: It could be done still. What you would need to do would be to make a daemon that periodically checks if an external display is connected, and when it is, place a no sleep assertion or run one of those utilities. This might help you get started: http://superuser.com/questions/278082/linux-how-to-run-a-script-when-an-external-monitor-is-connected

Comment: Thanks for the tip, that looks like the only way to do it. I was looking into Scenario (https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/scenario/id423444193?mt=12) but it looks like it doesn't detect when external power is plugged in or not.